# How to make the custom xml layout for this android project?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-widget, xml-layout

I am trying make application from this project: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

But here, there is a Layout that generating dynamicly. I want to create my own layout in xml file. So what should i have to do for it.

Please anyone can help me to make the xml layout from this dynamic layout ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That example is not creating a "dynamic layout".  The layout, which is the part you'd be defining in XML, consists of only one `View` object, `MyView`.

What I assume you are referring to by "dynamic layout" is the `MyView` class, which is a custom `View` object which accepts touch input and draws on the screen.  This cannot be defined in XML... you must write the Java code to handle the logic necessary, since the regular View class (which MyView is extending) does not support such functionality.

What you would need to do is create a Java file defining the MyView class.  Say for example, `com.example.MyView`. Then, in XML, you can include this custom view in your layout by referring to the full name, including the package name.  For example...

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.example.MyView>
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        </com.example.MyView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can use this layout in an activity as usual using `setContentView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Hope You have refer that project. In that Project MyView is the Subclass of the FingerPaint class. So to make such view possible, shouls i have to make the New class named as MyView or i can able to make the Layout of that sub class of the FingerPaint class ??